# htaccess and images redirect to watermarked image

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, proxy

Hey i have currently got a project that needs me to watermark images

Here is the direct Link:  http://zaramasonparty.teenbanter.net/uploads/1460220120945.jpg

Here is the watermarked Link:
http://zaramasonparty.teenbanter.net/view.php?img=1460220120945.jpg

can i make the direct image link proxy to the watermarked one?

i have a .htaccess file in /uploads and i have tried

```
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ http://zaramasonparty.teenbanter.net/view.php?img=$1 [NC,P]
```

i have also tried doing the same htaccess in the root dir

Comment: Do you mean to handling the redirect with `mod_proxy`?  Try swapping `[NC,P]` with `[NC,L]`

Comment: @GentlemanMax where should the htaccess file be?

Comment: It should be on the root of the site.

Comment: @GentlemanMax Not working

Comment: What happens? When I test your rule using [an `htaccess` tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/). It seems to look like it should be working.  Do you have any other rules in your `.htaccess` that might be conflicting?

Comment: @GentlemanMax I have no other htaccess rules at all on this site. do u can you message me in a way so i can just give FTP access

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot.  Are you sure that `mod_rewrite` is actually enabled?  That is where I would go from here.

Comment: @GentlemenMax i belive it is http://prntscr.com/dzfyci

Comment: Do you have an `Allow Override` Directive in your vhost?

Comment: Please just have a look at the phpinfo http://zaramasonparty.teenbanter.net/

Comment: i have got `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Then I would think it would work. Something odd is going on.  Do you get no image or the correct image?

Comment: @GentlemanMax I get the Real image not the watermarked one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do proxying, just a simple rewrite. Do this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ view.php?img=$1 [NC]
```